# Running total is incorrect after first iteration

Tags: excel, vba

[Current incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjPLC.png)

I want to compare a string value from a cell with a string value from another cell.  If they are the same, add another cell(a long) to a running total (volume), otherwise reset the running total and start over.

I'm adding the first comparison correctly, but the second comparison outputs 0(zero).

```
Sub stock_ticker()

'Placing headers for data
Cells(1, 9).Value = "<Stock Ticker>"
Cells(1, 10).Value = "<Yearly Total Trading Volume>"

'Setting up variables
Dim Ticker_Name As String
Dim Volume_Total, LastRow As LongLong
Dim i As Double
Dim Output_Row As LongLong

'Figure out the last row of the worksheet
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Volume_Total = 0
Ticker_Name = "A"
Output_Row = 2

For i = 2 To 2000

    'Check if we are still within the same ticker, if we are
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Ticker_Name Then

        'Add to Volume of that day to total
        Volume_Total = Volume_Total + Cells(i, 7).Value

    Else

        'Print the ticker in the results Stock Ticker column
        Cells(Output_Row, 9).Value = Ticker_Name

        'Print the volume total to the volume total column
        Cells(Output_Row, 10).Value = Volume_Total

        'Set the ticker name
        Ticker_Name = Cells(i, 9).Value

        'Reset the Volume Total
        Volume_Total = 0

        Output_Row = Output_Row + 1

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share your variable declarations, in order for us to properly help?

Comment: `Ticker_Name` probably needs a `.Value` as well as it is an object.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error when comparing the strings and not when adding to `Volume_Total`?

Comment: show us the the full code..

Comment: I added the full code.

Comment: `Dim Output_Row As LongLong` you only need `Long`...

Comment: @GSerg I could be, I changed the code to longs and it adds the first volume total, but then outputs zero after.  I'll added a picture.